# Java (remote) debugging by embedding beanshell?

Tags: java, remote-debugging, beanshell

I came across this post today: https://bukkit.org/threads/here-is-a-method-i-use-for-easier-debugging.1233/. It was meant for some java plugin.

I was wondering if the beanshell embedding method would generically work for any Java-based app? Could one expose a console/shell or a remote port connection to connect to for console access to beanshell with an instance of the currently running Java-based app? If so, what modifications are needed from the referenced link to make it work generically for any Java-based app?

I know some others in that thread mentioned to use IDE's remote debugging option. But it would be interesting and useful to have the beanshell option when you don't happen to have IDE/tooling around.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at FusionReactor - it provides a built in Java debugger which can be used for any Java-based app.  We did a recent blog post here - http://www.fusion-reactor.com/evangelism/remote-debugging-a-java-application-using-fusionreactor/